# PHP File upload not recieving file

Tags: php, html

I'm having a hard time using a HTML file input. Everytime i vardump the $_FILES array i can see it is completely empty: `array(0) { }` and the following notices:

```
Notice: Undefined index: upload in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\addproperty.sfwp on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: upload in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\addproperty.sfwp on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: upload in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\addproperty.sfwp on line 36`
```

Could someone have a look at my code?

HTML:

`<input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Afbeelding" name="upload">`

PHP:

```
$insert = $Properties->createProperty($catid,$typeid, $title, $price, $adressline1, $adressline2, $postalcode, $city, $province, $country, $sellerid, $avbedrooms, $avbathrooms, $avparkingspots, $claimsize, $livesize, $details);
    if($insert){
        echo $insert;
        var_dump($_FILES);
            $uploaddir = 'usrContent/';
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . "IMG_".$insert."_01.".end((explode(".", $_FILES['upload']['name'])));

            $ext = end((explode(".", $_FILES['upload']['name'])));

            if($ext != "png" || $ext != "jpeg" || $ext != "jpg"){

            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
            } else {
                echo "Upload went Wrong!\n";
            }
    }else{
        echo"2";
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure about  enctype="multipart/form-data" added to form

Comment: Thankyou Sir, I didn't knew it was that important but it solved my issue. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form..